# How do I use a transaction with a SCHEDULE statement?

Tags: mysql, transactions, cron, scheduler, rollback

I have 2 query in 1 scheduler.

Sample:

```
CREATE EVENT worker
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-12-22 00:00:00'
DO

INSERT INTO tbl1 (column) values ('foo')
UPDATE tbl2 SET column = 'foo'
```

I want to use transaction with this scheduler in MYSQL.

So, for example, if the error in the update query comes up, I want to rollback the insert query. How can I do that ?

Thx for reactions.

Comment: Just use `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;`. You don't need to use `ROLLBACK` here.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel write your comment as an answer, my dude, and maybe show where those statements go in the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your statements between `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;`. If any of the statements within the transaction will fail with an error, the `COMMIT` command will not be executed. Thus the changes will not be persisted and you don't need to rollback explicitly.

You can test it with the following script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl1`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl1` (
  `column` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl2`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl2` (
    `column` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `ts` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE INDEX `column` (`column`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `worker_log`;
CREATE TABLE `worker_log` (
    `ts` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `worker`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `worker` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND
STARTS NOW() + INTERVAL 10 SECOND
ENDS   NOW() + INTERVAL 70 SECOND
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN
    INSERT INTO worker_log (`ts`) values (NOW());
    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO tbl1 (`column`) values ('foo');
        INSERT INTO tbl2 (`column`) values ('foo');
    COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;

SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Now wait a minute and look what has been written to your tables:

```
select * from worker_log;

ts
-------------------
2017-12-23 16:24:44
2017-12-23 16:24:54
2017-12-23 16:25:04
2017-12-23 16:25:14
2017-12-23 16:25:24
2017-12-23 16:25:34
2017-12-23 16:25:44
```

You see that the event has been executed every 10 seconds (as defined).

```
select * from tbl1;

column | ts
-------+-----------------------
foo    | 2017-12-23 16:24:44

select * from tbl2;

column | ts
-------+--------------------
foo    | 2017-12-23 16:24:44
```

But here you see that the statements within the transaction had only an effect on the first run. This is because the `column` on `tbl2` is defined as `UNIQUE`, and the second statement failed after the first run, because it tried to insert the same value into this column. But though the first statement should run without problems (since `tbl1.column` is not `UNIQUE`), it has also not been persisted.